# Call GraphQL API with String variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphql

I want to execute a simple `GraphQL` query in which I pass a variable.

```
import requests
import json

var = "whatever"

query = """
    query ($var: String!){
        styles(locale: "en", styleNumbers: [ $var] ) {
            styleOptions {
    parms {
        parm1
        parm2
            }
        }
        }
    }
"""

url = 'https://sth_random.io/graphql?'
response = requests.get(url, json={'query': query, '$var': var})
response = response.json()

print(response)
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
{'errors': [{'message': 'Variable "$var" of required type "String!" was not provided.', 'locations': [{'line': 2, 'column': 12}]}]}
```

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The request body should include a `variables` key that is itself a dictionary of the variable values:

```
variables = {'var': var}
response = requests.post(url, json={'query': query, 'variables': variables})
```

Comment: Actually this is what I tried but I thought it wasn't very important and I tried to simplify my example. Although the error remains exactly the same.

Comment: I changed that but the error remains. As I understand it is not that the call is rejected. The variable is not passed in the query.

Comment: My bad. While you prepend a `$` to the variable names in the query itself, you omit the `$` inside the `variables` object. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: We do have progress as I do not get an error, but the response is: {'data': {'styles': []}} so I understand that it doesn't point to the element of the dictionary. The variables = {'var': var} pair has a value which should return a full response.

Comment: If the server you're querying exposes a GraphiQL or GraphQL Playground interface, you can use that to test the same query. If you get the same response, then the issue is not with the client code above.